# JSP interpreting <> as html tags and adding end tag

Tags: html, jsp, tags

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am saving some text in database and then displaying it. But for example, if I add something like `<hello123>` in text field, it is saved in database the same, but while display it becomes `<hello123></hello123>`. What can I do to avoid JSP displaying those end tags. I am posting how I am displaying the code. Thanks a lot.

JSP code :

```
<div class="inner-div">
        <span class="notice-text">${notices.mnotetext}</span>
    <span style="display:none"class="ellipsis"><span class="dots"> ... 
   </span><span class="more">mehr</span></span>
 </div>
```

I am displaying the mnotetext and it is getting messed up, what can I do? Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

*Edit* Changes as described by Thomas.

```
  <div class="inner-div">
<span class="notice-text">&lt;hello&gt;</span>  <span style="display:none"class="ellipsis"><span class="dots"> ... /span><span class="more">mehr</span></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like the browser is performing error recovery on your invalid HTML, which has nothing to do with JSP. The solution is to not send invalid HTML to the browser in the first place.

Comment: @Quentin : That is avoiding the problem, these are notes which I am saving, I cannot enforce such rules. Do you know a workaround?

Comment: If you are expecting people to write raw HTML, then it is not unreasonable to require that they write valid HTML or accept that it is going to be error corrected. If you are expecting people to write plain text, then you shouldn't treat it as HTML by injecting it into an HTML document in its raw form (i.e. you should convert it to HTML first).

Comment: @Quentin : I don't see such corrections happening in Stackoverflow for example.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't let you write raw HTML. It parses the input as Markdown and outputs HTML.

Comment: @Quentin : If there is any easy way to do it, can you please share it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are plenty of markdown libraries out there. I'd be surprised if you can't find one for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending unesacped HTML in your output. Try escaping the value like shown below. Which will also prevent XSS attack.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<div class="inner-div">
    <span class="notice-text"> <c:out value="${notices.mnotetext}"/> </span>
    <span style="display:none"class="ellipsis"><span class="dots"> ... 
    </span><span class="more">mehr</span></span>
</div>
```

Here is  js fiddle just showing the tag alone in the html output. https://jsfiddle.net/4hg547s4/

Comment: Please select the generated HTML in your browser and click on view source. Please paste the response here

Comment: Please check the main post, I have added the edit there. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Is the issue solved now? Based on the edit you should be seeing the proper text in the UI now. If the above solution solved the issue mark it as the answer :)

Comment: If this did not solve the issue, please don't mark it as the answer. Since others might not be able to help you. I am not understanding your requirement properly. Hope someone else might be able to help you with the issue.